# question about timezone in postgresql+java?

Tags: java, postgresql

I am using postgresql9.0 and JDK6.
I am running pg_controldata command in postgresql. in that I need "Time of latest checkpoint:" value. it is a date & time with timezone.

while running through java API it is dispalying everything otherthan timezone.

from direct postgres it it showing ---Time of latest checkpoint:Mon 12 Mar 2012 08:15:43 AM SGT

but when run through code then it is showing----Time of latest checkpoint:Mon Mar 12 08:15:43 2012

how to solve it?

```
String result = 
pe.executepsql("/data/PostgreSQL/bin/pg_controldata /data/PostgreSQL/data"); 
System.out.println("Output of cmd:" +result); 
String start = "Time of latest checkpoint:"; 
String end = "Minimum recovery ending location:"; 
String str = result.substring(result.indexOf(start)+
"Time of latest checkpoint:".length(),result.indexOf(end)).trim(); 
System.out.println("Time of latest checkpoint: " +str); 
executepsql()
```

is used to execute postgres command.

executepsql() is used to execute postgres command.

I tried psql -c command also with this method which is working fine. but pg_controldata is not working correctly.

Comment: show us the code which doesn't display the timezone.

Comment: String result = pe.executepsql("/data/PostgreSQL/bin/pg_controldata /data/PostgreSQL/data");
         System.out.println("Output of cmd:" +result);
         String start = "Time of latest checkpoint:";
         String end = "Minimum recovery ending location:";
         String str = result.substring(result.indexOf(start)+"Time of latest checkpoint:".length(),result.indexOf(end)).trim();
           
         System.out.println("Time of latest checkpoint: " +str);                                                               executepsql() is used to execute postgres command.

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = pe.executepsql("/data/PostgreSQL/bin/pg_controldata /data/PostgreSQL/data");
System.out.println("Output of cmd:" +result);
String start = "Time of latest checkpoint:";
String end = "Minimum recovery ending location:";
String str = result.substring(result.indexOf(start)+"Time of latest checkpoint:".length(),result.indexOf(end)).trim();
System.out.println("Time of latest checkpoint: " +str);
```

executepsql() is used to execute postgres command.

I tried psql -c command also with this method which is working fine. but pg_controldata is not working correctly.